# Code goes beyond the box, allowing you to scroll the whole post

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, code-block, scrolling

You're able to scroll the whole post! This shouldn't happen. I believe the correct behavior is to not scroll the post, but scroll the gray code box that pops up when you click on it.

Android 5.1.1 on a Galaxy S6.

The problem question is [Cannot add noexec to fstab /tmp/](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/227120/20282)

> [image: A question on UNIX.SE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.0.84.

As Andrew mentioned, the `<pre>` tag did not contain a `<code>` tag.  On the web and iOS the `<pre>` tag is scrollable but on Android the `<code>` tag was scrollable so the little arrow in the top right corner could be absolutely positioned over the `<pre>`.

I'm sure I could eventually figure out a pure CSS way to position that element over a scrolling `<pre>` but instead I'm injecting a parent node to wrap the `<pre>`, making that element have the arrow icon, and making the `<pre>` scrollable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is SE's fault, SE app's fault, or the editor's fault, but it's related to... undefined formatting.

As far as I know, the [official formatting help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) mentions this:

> ## Code and Preformatted Text
>
> Indent four spaces to create an escaped `<pre> <code>` block:

The linked question use `<pre></pre>` only, which is problematic on SE app, as it considers as code-block, but not allowing in-block scroll. However, desktop browser (at least tested on Chrome 45, Win7) rendered all formatting correctly.

You can see the difference when seeing this answer from Android SE app.

---

This one is only using `<pre></pre>` (problematic).

```
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
/dev/mapper/ol_rhel7-root /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=af6b8325-9cf7-4618-9afd-99987eb8f3b3 /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/ol_rhel7-home /home                   xfs     defaults,nodev        0 0
/dev/mapper/ol_rhel7-var /var                     xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/ol_rhel7-swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
/dev/sda5          /var/log                       xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/sdb1          /var/log/audit                 xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/sdc1          /tmp                           xfs     defaults,nodev,nosuid           0 0
/tmp               /var/tmp                       none    bind   0 0
tmpfs              /dev/shm                       tmpfs   defaults,nodev,nosuid,noexec     0 0
```

This use `<pre><code></code></pre>` (rendered properly).

```
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
/dev/mapper/ol_rhel7-root /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=af6b8325-9cf7-4618-9afd-99987eb8f3b3 /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/ol_rhel7-home /home                   xfs     defaults,nodev        0 0
/dev/mapper/ol_rhel7-var /var                     xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/ol_rhel7-swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
/dev/sda5          /var/log                       xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/sdb1          /var/log/audit                 xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/sdc1          /tmp                           xfs     defaults,nodev,nosuid           0 0
/tmp               /var/tmp                       none    bind   0 0
tmpfs              /dev/shm                       tmpfs   defaults,nodev,nosuid,noexec     0 0
```

This is the standard 4-space code formatting (rendered properly).

```
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
/dev/mapper/ol_rhel7-root /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=af6b8325-9cf7-4618-9afd-99987eb8f3b3 /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/ol_rhel7-home /home                   xfs     defaults,nodev        0 0
/dev/mapper/ol_rhel7-var /var                     xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/ol_rhel7-swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
/dev/sda5          /var/log                       xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/sdb1          /var/log/audit                 xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/sdc1          /tmp                           xfs     defaults,nodev,nosuid           0 0
/tmp               /var/tmp                       none    bind   0 0
tmpfs              /dev/shm                       tmpfs   defaults,nodev,nosuid,noexec     0 0
```