# Bugged long code view in Android app?

Tags: bug, android-app, code-block

When there's a long code section without a new line, I'm able to scroll horizontally, but the box moves instead of the code inside it.

I'm on Android 6.0.1 using SE app v1.0.83.

[Example post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3058938/2821954)

[image: bug]

Comment: What's the app version? Also, could you provide the direct link to the problematic answer to make this easier to debug? Currently it looks like a dupe to http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264738/241919

Comment: The app version is 1.0.83, but I forgot the question link, sorry

Comment: I found the SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3058938/2821954, and the issue is the same as the linked bug report, which has been fixed on 1.0.84.

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer!